# NullPointerException's on StartActivityForResult, Struggling with SQLite in android i think?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-activity, android-intent

I have one class called Budget.java, within that i start Keypad.java. This was all working fine up until recently when i added a bunch of code to Keypad.java (The added code was to update a row in my SQLite database on the press of a button, all the unrelated methods were working until i tried to implement this). Now using breakpoints i think i've figured out that i get the error message as soon as i try to open the Keypad activity and i don't have a clue what could be the problem.

Maybe it's my misunderstanding of the sqlite open helper? Or perhaps its because i'm using StartActivityForResult?

Any suggestions would be very appreciated! I can upload the logcat if you think that would help.
I uploaded the two little classes to pastebin, you might find it easier to read?

[Budget.java ( look for ListItemCommonIntent )](http://pastebin.com/LX61QzdS)

[keypad.java](http://pastebin.com/KjbKbka5)

Comment: `I can upload the logcat if you think that would help` : Adding a logcat is always a good idea :)

Comment: adding the class and line where NullPointerException is thrown would be a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Keypad.java`, you have the following outside the `onCreate`:

```
 EditText userAmount=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.cost_input);
```

This wont work because you have to use the `setContentView` to reference the layout where you want to find the view. And when it initializes `userAmount`, the object is not available yet (so `this` is null) .

Try this:

```
private EditText userAmount;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.keypad);
    userAmount=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cost_input);
    MySpinner();
    Main();
}
```

Comment: OHHH thank you! jeez that must have been something really stupid i did when i was moving things around, i've been pouring over this class for days i don't know how i missed that. what an idiot i am, Thanks.